# BUBBLE SORT Help in C . line-based questions from a source code

Tags: c, arrays, prototype

http://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-sorting-bubble-sort/

My questions are:

1. At line 28:  Why `num - i - 1?`
2. At line 30: what does the `if` condition mean? especially, why `j + 1`?
3. How to display the elements of the sorted array randomly? No Asc or Dsc order?
4. How to differ in the displayed random numbers?

Comment: Write a bunch a papers with the values in the input array. Order them manually using the Bubble sort algorithm. Note the differences (or similarities) between your (manual) implementation and the C program implementation in that site.

Comment: right on it,thanks @pmg

Comment: Why downvoting him ? He learns C.

Comment: @peace_in_code i added answer, that is simple logic and you can change logic in your own way. so many ways are there to bubble sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at Line 30 code is doing `j+1` that is why the condition is `j<num-i-1` so that array out of bound exception will not occur.

you can change the logic as

```
for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j < (num - i); j++)
        {
            if (array[j-1] > array[j])
            {
                temp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j-1];
                array[j-1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

if you want to display array in random way then there is no need of sorting!! because there is already no order in array.

you can write your own logic to display array elements randomly.

Comment: I prefer to start my `for` loop as `j=0` but yeah that's insightful.

Comment: @peace_in_code it depends upon your choice but both will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Because we're going to be adding one to the index, we can't loop up to `num - i` or we'd overshoot.
2. That adds one to the index to look at, and compare, the `j`:th with the (`j + 1`):th elements.
3. That doesn't make a lot of sense. If you want to display it randomly, don't sort it. "Shuffle" is the term for randomizing an array.
4. No idea what you mean there.

Comment: what do you mean when you speak of 'index'?

Comment: @peace_in_code Index is the term often used for the location in an array that is being accessed. So in the expression `array[i]`, `i` is the index. The square brackets `[]` are often called the array-index operator for this reason. The C standard uses the term "array subscripting", but you often hear it called "indexing".

Comment: In that `if` condition `j` cannot be greater than `j+1` right? then how is the statement still executing?I might be missing something.

Comment: @peace_in_code The comparison is not between `j` and `j + 1`, it's using those to index into `array`. It's the contents of the array at those two locations that is being compared.

Answer (score 0):

1) num is the number of numbers to sort. i is the number of elements already sorted and 1 is for the number that will be sorted.
In the loop it compares the element at array[j] and array[j+1] to see if they need to be swapped. The loop should then stop when j is the before last to test and j+1 is the last to test. This is why j starts from 0 and ends when j is num - i - 1.

2) it compares the number at position j with the number at position j+1. If you would write the numbers in sequence in a line from left to right, this would be a comparison between the number at position j and the number that follows it (right to it).

3) you would have to create an array of element index. This array would be initialized with values from 0 to num-1. You would then iterate over this array and swap the entry with another entry chosen randomly. To do this you pick a random number between 0 and num-1. This will shuffle the element index array. 
To print the numbers in random order, you would use the value stored in the element index array as index of the next number to display. This ensure the order is random, that each number is displayed only once and that all numbers are displayed.

4° I don't understand that question.

Comment: Now i get it.  Question 3) and 4) are the same so no worries there.  I used a `rand()` function in another program to display random values.How do i seed it? Its giving me same values everytime i run it.what function to use?